# Stacking multiple date and search string queries SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to clean up my code. The following code works as expected but I can't figure out how you stack the date query's similar to the incidentType which utilises the 'IN' query. There just seems so much code to do the same thing just a different set of dates. I know it will be something to do with brackets around and using commas but i have tried and tried with no luck.
Here is my working code:

```
SELECT * FROM sa_incidents 
WHERE
    (incidentDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31' )
    AND
    incidentType 
    IN (
        'RIDDOR - Dangerous Occurrence',
        'RIDDOR - Public',
        'Non RIDDOR - Near Miss',
        'Non RIDDOR - Minor Injury'
    )
    OR (incidentDate  BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31')
    AND
    incidentType 
    IN (
        'RIDDOR - Dangerous Occurrence',
        'RIDDOR - Public',
        'Non RIDDOR - Near Miss',
        'Non RIDDOR - Minor Injury'
    )
    OR 
    (incidentDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31' )
    AND
    incidentType 
    IN (
        'RIDDOR - Dangerous Occurrence',
        'RIDDOR - Public',
        'Non RIDDOR - Near Miss',
        'Non RIDDOR - Minor Injury'
    )
```

Comment: Hi JohnM, you could have a look at the CASE statement. I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: What happened to 2018 - You got something against 2018?

Comment: Couldn't you just code `incidentDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'` assuming missing out 2018 was a mistake

Comment: @RiggsFolly :-) No just didn't want someone to suggest expanding the first part over the 2 years or more ;-) which would instantly half the code Ha Ha. The dates are called in by another part of my code in PHP. So they could be anything i just used those as an example

Comment: @RobBlagg I think you are correct in the way forwards will be utilising the CASE statement i had a quick look using google and it should do want i want. Just need to figure out how to put it together but that part of the fun :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to reduce the unnecessary coding this would do it

```
SELECT * FROM sa_incidents 
WHERE (
            incidentDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
        OR  incidentDate  BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
        OR  incidentDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
        )
AND incidentType IN (
                        'RIDDOR - Dangerous Occurrence',
                        'RIDDOR - Public',
                        'Non RIDDOR - Near Miss',
                        'Non RIDDOR - Minor Injury'
                    )
ORDER BY <something like the data probably>
```

Comment: That does exactly what i needed it to do. I tried exactly that in a round about way 10 different version but that!! Thank you!

Comment: You always need to be careful of OR, they always mean you need to bracket things to make sure it, and us dont get confused :)